# ¿Es esta conexión a BD segura ? (JAVA)

Tags: java, mysql

Buenas estoy empezando a hacer un proyecto con el prototipo de MVC (modelo,vista,controlador) y pues he visto distintas conexiones y casi todas son similares por lo que he decidido hacer la mia y me gustaria saber si la que tengo es segura(que personas malintencionadas puedan acceder) o si así esta correctamente. En tal caso que no sea segura si pueden proporcionarme información,videos o paginas donde me pudieran enriquecer de conocimiento se los agradeceria.

```
package conexion;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Conexion {
    public static String url = "";
    public static String usuario = "";
    public static String contraseña = "";
    public static String clase = "";

public static Connection conectar (){
    Connection conexion = null;

    try {
        Class.forName(clase); 
        conexion = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,contraseña);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Conexion con exito");

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error"+e);
    }
return conexion;
}
```

Muchas gracias por la atencion prestada

Comment: La pregunta parece basada en opiniones y eso generará su cierre

Answer (score 0):

Por defecto las conexiones a bases de datos son tìpicamente inseguras. Se espera que los datos circulen entre la aplicación y la base de datos sólo dentro de segmentos seguros de red.

La base de datos no debería estar expuesta al resto de la red, sino que sólo a los servidores de aplicación. Mucho menos, la base de datos no debería estar expuesta abiertamente a la internet.

Hay que considerar que sí se puede implementar SSL/TLS en la conexión. Hay hartos ejemplos de esto. Sin embargo, estos ejemplos apuntan a conexiones internas a la organización que usan segmentos de red *semi* seguros; no para exponer tu base de datos a internet.